# OpenLayers: Load cached tiles only if present, otherwise get them online

Tags: gis, openlayers

I have two layers, OpenStreetMap for online tiles and TMS for cached tiles from a different tile source. I know how to display each of the layers separately.

However, TMS does not contain all the tiles. So I would like to display TMS tiles first and then everything else that is not cached with OpenStreetMap. How could I do this overlapping of two layers?

The result should look just like below:
[a busy cat http://tothchat.com/test/tiles.png](http://tothchat.com/test/tiles.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This two layers must be overlay (not baseLayer). Did you try this:

```
map = new OpenLayers.Map({
        div: "map",
        allOverlays: true  //<- all layers will have isBaseLayer set to false when they are added to the map.
    });
```

Or set `isBaseLayer` parameter to **false** for these two layers.

Comment: Thanks, I have not tried because I do not need to solve the problem anymore. But it looks promising.